# Edit TFS team build definition using C#

Tags: c#, windows, tfsbuild

I am a beginner to DevOps and I am working on building a windows desktop application using c# .Net which can edit the parameters of a TFS team build definition from a list of build definitions. The way I want the UI to be is

Select the team project ==> Select the build definition ==> select the parameters to edit.

I am stuck at the very first step as to how do I populate my dropdown commbo box with a list of the team projects in my collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TeamProjectPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamprojectpicker.aspx) class from TFS object model. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/04/20/using-the-teamprojectpicker-api-in-tfs-2010.aspx) blog post for the details on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Before writing your own tool, consider what is already available in the community. To manage a large set of builds [Community TFS Build Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f) is the best option.

Consider looking at [their code in GitHub](https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/BuildManager), if you really need to write your own.